# Authenticating different kinds of users

Tags: database, authentication

In my web application I have multiple types of users, say in tables `Customer (id, name, password, ...)` and `Admin (id, name, password, ...)`. Both of these need to be authenticated.  I wonder which method is the most sensible:

1. Using the two tables, having two kinds of authentication cookies, possibly two sets of `login`, `logout`, `isAuthenticated` methods. I'd like to do this, but I feel that web frameworks don't make this easy.
2. Cramming the two tables into `User (id, name, password, role, columns_for_customer, columns_for_admin)`. This is probably the simplest and most efficient option. Though I find it ugly as it leaves half the table unused. Assume `Customer` and `Admin` to share very few actions.
3. Adding a new table `User (id, name, password, customer_id, admin_id)`. A middle ground. I feel particularly uneasy about moving `name` out of the `Customer` and `Admin` tables (or duplicating it there).

I'm looking for an answer about *best practices*.

Answer (score 0):

You should have ONE table, and a auxiliary table to store permission data, and or columns for customer.

Two tables is bad because one user can have two records. What happens when that user changes an email address?

Your person table should only have information on id, username, password, email.

You should have a permissions table with a FK into person.id, and a customer_info table with a FK to person.id

This way you have normalized your data using best practices.